# copy text box content to another textbox while typing

Tags: jquery

I writing j query which copy content from one text box into another.
am not an expert in j query following in mine code

```
    $(function() {
    $('input[id$=tb1]').keyup(function() {
        var txtClone = $(this).val();
        $('input[id$=txtCustName]').val(txtClone);
    });
});
```

Comment: you are missing quotes for your selector also

Comment: post the html... no way to know if selector is correct or not without seeing html

Comment: I thought the quotes were optional?

Comment: @Greg ..they used to be optional but newer versions of jQuery got more stringent, sometimes work without..safer to add them though

Comment: @charlietfl According to this http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/ the value "can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string"

Comment: @Greg   perhaps docs need to be changed, but this is a common issue since about jQuery 1.6, look at every example on main selector api page  http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Just a note... when people are working with text, they might also use the mouse to copy/cut/paste text. Your approach will not keep those changes in sync.

Answer (score 9):

try this js:

```
$('input[id$=tb1]').on('keyup',function() {
    $('input[id$=txtCustName]').val($(this).val());
});
```

use jQuery's [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind to the event is much better, and you don't have to set the val to a variable first...

**EDIT**

the above code will clone the content into any field ending with `txtCustName` if you have html like:

```
<input id="random_tb1"/>
<input id="text_txtCustName"/>
<input id="other_tb1"/>
<input id="stuff_txtCustName"/>
```

it has no idea which one you want, so if you make your html something like this:

```
<div>
    <input id="random_tb1"/>
    <input id="text_txtCustName"/>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="other_tb1"/>
    <input id="stuff_txtCustName"/>
</div>
```

you can keep them separated in html, and only update the related field with this JS:

```
$(function() {

    $('input[id$=tb1]').on('keyup',function() {
        $('input[id$=txtCustName]',$(this).parent()).val($(this).val());
    });

});​
```

here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JKirchartz/XN2qD/

Comment: He is using the ends with selector for the id so this is not quite right.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem anything wrong with the code you have supplied.

Ive recreated it using JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/e9KFT/

Could we have more info? A snippet of your HTML markup would be a good start!

Answer (score 0):

It's Simple.
Just write these codes.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" value="" /> <br >
    <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" value="" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#text1').keyup(function(){
        $('#text2').val($(this).val());
      });
    });
</script>
```

You can see it here https://jsfiddle.net/prasant200582/x7jzk0pg/5/