# How can I fill all text inputs with same value with no id required?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So what I want to do is fill text inputs, with the same input value. Here is an example form.

```
    <button class="btn">Fill All</button>
    <input type ="text" class="inpt" ></input>
    <input type ="text" class="inpt" ></input>
    <input type ="text" class="inpt" ></input>
    <input type ="text" class="inpt" ></input>
```

I saw a javascript example what takes the name of an input and fills it that way and saw a Jquery example what does this by id here: [copy text box content to another textbox while typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943984/copy-text-box-content-to-another-textbox-while-typing) but how can I do this when there are no ids assigned and all the classes and names have the same value. I am kind of novice in Jquery, js and too dumb to figure it out, couldn't find any examples for it also.

Edit: Thanks for nice answers, but is there a way to get the value from like first or any text boxes and fill the others with that value.

Comment: `</input>` --- not valid

Comment: Use a selector function, `$(".btn").nextAll(".inpt").val("something")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you need ?

```css
$(function(){
   $('.btn').on('click', function(){
     var $value = $('input').val();
     $(".inpt").val($value);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<button class="btn">Fill All</button>
<input type ="text" class="inpt" />
<input type ="text" class="inpt" />
<input type ="text" class="inpt" />
<input type ="text" class="inpt" />
```

Comment: Kind of, but is there a way I could get the value from  like first input field and fill the next inputs with that value?

Comment: i dont understand it, you want to type first input value then click button the value paste all inputs right ?

Comment: pretty much yeah, if that's possible

Comment: can you check now

Comment: Yea, it´s working, thanks a lot man. It seems way easier than I thought, but learning I guess.

Comment: @Skyhigh17 Thanks Dear

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `onkeyup` event on input field and copy the value to others
One more thing , `input` is a singleton HTML tag and hence you don't close is like `</input>` rather `<input {some parameters here}/>`.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.inpt').on('keyup', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('.inpt').val(val);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type ="text" class="inpt" />
    <input type ="text" class="inpt" />
    <input type ="text" class="inpt" />
    <input type ="text" class="inpt" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code that solves your question, good luck!

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" class="btn" onclick="fillAll()" value="Fill All"></input>
<input type ="text" class="inpt" />
<input type ="text" class="inpt" />
<input type ="text" class="inpt" />
<input type ="text" class="inpt" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
  function fillAll(){

        var inputArray = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

      for(var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++){
        if(inputArray[i].getAttribute("type") != "button"){
            inputArray[i].value = "hello!";
        }
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an example how could it be done:

Binded on `keyup` amy input, then save it's value and replace all other inputs with it's value, and after that focusing again same input so the user can continue typing.

```js
$(function(){
  $('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function(){
      value = $(this).val();
      $('input[type="text"]').val( value );
      $(this).focus();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">Fill All</button>
    <input type ="text" class="inpt" />
    <input type ="text" class="inpt" />
    <input type ="text" class="inpt" />
    <input type ="text" class="inpt" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class you can try :

```
 $('input').keyup(function() {
    var txtClone = $(this).val();
    $('input[class$=inpt]').val(txtClone);
});
```